# How to get Firestore information actually added to a list so the list can passed to other functions later on

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm really new to programming in general. My question is that I know when reading from Firestore, it is asynchronous. Meaning if I do:

```
        Log.d("data_base", "got here 1");
        getFeeds();
        Log.d("data_base", "got here 2");
```

"got here 1" and "got here 2" will be printed simultaneously despite any log statement inside `getFeeds()`

But what if I do want to store all the information from a Firestore collection into a list and use it later on?

This is what I have now.

```
    List<String> username = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> imageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    getFeeds();
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(username, imageUrl);
```

```
    private void getFeeds() {
        db.collection("feeds").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d("data_base", "listen:error");
                    return;
                }
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                    if(doc.get("image") != null) {
                        Log.d("data_base", doc.getString("image"));
                        imageUrl.add(doc.getString("image"));
                    }
                    if (doc.get("username") != null) {
                        username.add(doc.getString("username"));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I only need one line

```
    private void getFeeds(final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter) {
        db.collection("feeds").orderBy("username", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d("data_base", "listen:error");
                    return;
                }
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                    if(doc.get("image") != null) {
                        Log.d("data_base", doc.getString("image"));
                        imageUrl.add(doc.getString("image"));
                    }
                    if (doc.get("username") != null) {
                        username.add(doc.getString("username"));
                    }
                }
                // added line here               
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

My understanding is when onEvent() finish fetching data from Firestore, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will be called to update the two lists.

Comment: Nice, could you please upvote your own answer? IN this way other community members can easily identify the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Lists to save data from firestore collection.

1. To store data in firestore collection you can use Hashmap. Code attached below:

   ```
    HashMap<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
    userData.put("username", your_username_data);
    userData.put("imageurl", your_imageurl_data);

    db.collection("feeds").document().set(userData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            //This code gets executed if data successfully added to db
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Data save successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            `enter code here`//This code gets executed if data cannot be saved to db
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
   ```
2. To fetch data from firestore collection you can refer to the code below:

   ```
    db.collection("feeds").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            // Code below gets executed if data fetched successfully
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    String username = (String) documentSnapshot.get("username"); // this is your username previously saved to db
                    String imageurl = (String) documentSnapshot.get("imageurl"); // this is your imageurl previously saved to db
                    // Bonus: to download images to your imageview you can use Glide library (I will attach link below to Github page)
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageurl).into(imageview); // imageview is your ImageView that you want to show your images
                }
            }
        }
    });
   ```
3. If you want to use your data later in your other activity you should use Bundle. Code provided below:

   In your 1st Activity (Activity that you want to pass data from):

   ```
    String username = your_username_data;
    String imageurl = your_imageurl_data;
    Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("username", username);
    i.putExtra("imageurl", imageurl);
    startActivity(i);
   ```

   In your 2nd Activity (Activity that you want to pass data to):

   ```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String username = extras.getString("username"); 
        String imageurl = extras.getString("imageurl");
        // inside extras.getString you use key value (value in quote "") which you provided inside i.putExtra
    }
   ```

Link: https://github.com/bumptech/glide (this library helps you to download image urls to imageviews)

Comment: Thank you but I think I figured it out!